# Two tables which have different engines can't have foreign keys?

Tags: mysql

I have table A (innoDB) and table B (MyISAM). When I add foreign keys from A to B. It reports:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)
```

Why is it?

Comment: it is not possible. only innodb support foreign keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) does not support [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Both table needs to be InnoDB.

Change engine to InnoDB first.

Comment: Table A is innoDB ---> Table B is MyISAM, is it impossible?

Comment: Once again, to use foreign keys, both tables needs to be InnoDB.